# Counting in fives when producing list

Tags: php

Given that:

```
$min=30
$max=60
```

(min and max being variables that are rounded either to the nearest 5 or 10)

How do you generate an output that counts in five within the min and max range in a table format?

For example with the above example you would get an output of:

> ```
> cname  |
> -------|
> 30     |
> -------|
> 35     |
> -------|
> 40     |
> -------|
> 45     |
> -------|
> 50     |
> -------|
> 55     |
> -------|
> 60     |
> -------|
> ```

Comment: `for( $i = $min; $i <= $max; $i+=5 )`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minor variant on the above answers

```
foreach(range($min,$max,5) as $value) {
    //  do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for ($i = 30; $i <= 50; $i+=5) {
    echo $i;
}
```

For more information have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Or `$ranges = range(30, 60, 5);`. :)